# Variable 'reader' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at run time

Tags: vb.net

Trying to fix a warning and not sure how to restructure code as reader.IsClosed is throwing a warning that states "Variable 'reader' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at run time."  Logistically, since reader As SqlDataReader  && reader is not initialized with a value then I could ignore as should be fine at runtime, but my inexperience would make me believe there is a better way?

```
Public Function GetTotalItems(ByVal userId As Long) As Int16

    Dim lstParam As List(Of SqlParameter) = New List(Of SqlParameter)()
    Dim tablMd = Me.GetMetaData()
    Dim retList As ArrayList = New ArrayList()

    lstParam.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@" + tablMd.PrimaryKey.ColumnName, 0))
    lstParam.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@UserID", userId))
    lstParam.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@ActionFlag", "SELECT_ITEMS_COUNT"))

    Dim spName As String = Me.GetStoreProcname()
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader
    Try
        reader = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(
            Utility.GetConnectionStringSetting(),
            CommandType.StoredProcedure,
            Me.GetStoreProcname(),
            lstParam.ToArray()
        )

        If (reader.HasRows = True) Then
            If (reader.Read()) Then
                Dim value As Object = reader(0)

                Return CInt(value)

            End If

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw

    Finally
        If Not reader.IsClosed Then
            reader.Close()
        End If
    End Try

    Return 0

End Function
```

Comment: Hint: `Dim reader As SqlDataReader` needs to be modified, DIY for you. Also you better start using `using`

Comment: To be more specific, you are assuming that `reader` has a value when you get its `IsClosed` property in your `Finally` block but if your `SqlHelper.ExecuteReader` method throws an exception then `reader` will not have a value at that point.

Comment: Also, your `Catch` block is totally pointless. You don't need a `Catch` block if you have a `Finally` block so don't add one if you're not going to do anything in it. As suggested though, you should be using a `Using` block.  If you do that then you can do away with the whole `Try...Catch...Finally` because it will achieve the same thing without the possibility of a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Adding to what @jmcilhinney briefly explained, keep [Options Strict & Explicit ON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454552/what-do-option-strict-and-option-explicit-do).

Comment: If  you create your reader in a `Using` block you won't need to close it in a finally block, plus you will eliminate the warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can narrow the problem down to this excerpt:

```
Dim reader As SqlDataReader
Try
    reader = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader( ... )
Finally
    If Not reader.IsClosed Then reader.Close()
End Try
```

The problem comes if an exception is thrown by the `ExecuteReader()` function. In that event, the `reader` variable is never assigned a value. It's still `Nothing` when you try to evaluate `reader.IsClosed`, and *that* will cause an exception.

Given you don't actually do anything with the exception and the `SqlHelper` takes care of the connection and command objects, you can narrow the entire function down to just this:

```
Public Function GetTotalItems(ByVal userId As Long) As Int16
    Dim lstParam = {
       New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@" + Me.GetMetaData().PrimaryKey.ColumnName, 0),
       New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@UserID", userId),
       New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@ActionFlag", "SELECT_ITEMS_COUNT")
    }

    Using reader As SqlDataReader = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(
            Utility.GetConnectionStringSetting(),
            CommandType.StoredProcedure,
            Me.GetStoreProcname(),
            lstParam)

        If reader.Read() Then Return CInt(reader(0))
    End Using

    Return 0  
End Function
```

Comment: So the (reader.HasRows = True) is implicit and is checked before reading so the nested If statements are not required? ... Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

@jmcilhinney, @o_O, @Chris Dunaway ... Thank you for the help + appreciation + admiration for your knowledge + reverence == `deverence();` ... This removed the error:

Public Function GetTotalAmount(ByVal userId As Long) As Decimal

```
    Dim lstParam As List(Of SqlParameter) = New List(Of SqlParameter)()
    Dim tablMd = Me.GetMetaData()
    Dim retList As ArrayList = New ArrayList()

    lstParam.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@" + tablMd.PrimaryKey.ColumnName, 0))
    lstParam.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@UserID", userId))
    lstParam.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@ActionFlag", "SELECT_TOTAL_AMOUNT"))

    Dim spName As String = Me.GetStoreProcname()


    Using reader As SqlDataReader = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(
            Utility.GetConnectionStringSetting(),
            CommandType.StoredProcedure,
            Me.GetStoreProcname(),
            lstParam.ToArray()
        )

        If (reader.HasRows = True) Then
                If (reader.Read()) Then
                    Dim value As Object = reader(0)

                    Return CDec(value)
                End If
            End If
    End Using

    Return 0

End Function
```